# Spring, numeric validation, default value, warning message

Tags: java, spring, constraints, default-value

I have bean definition, e.g.

```
<bean id="DsdDetectorLogic" class="my class" init-method="init" lazy-init="true" >
    <property name="threshold" value="#{ properties.threshold }" />
    <property name="lag" value="#{ properties.lag }" />
    ...
</bean>
```

I need to add constrains on specific parameter (*lag*), if this parameter exceeds max value of 3 or min value of 1 , i need it to get a default value of 1. Additionally i need to receive some warning message that this parameter received a default value as a result.

I familiar with a solution of using javax.validation.constraints.Min / Max for the annotation of fields inside the code.

Is it possible to use some spring feature to edit the xml file, or the only solution is to do it from the java object class during the time when setters are invoked?

Comment: Looking over http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html I didn't see anything about what your asking. However, section 3.3 mentions about setting constructor values. If this is a custom class of yours, you might be able to achieve something similar this way.

Comment: @Jesse J: i have a found a way to partially solve my question, may be you can help to find how to show a warning message? (my answer is attached)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question partially, since i found how i can check the constrains and send a default value through xml, warning message is still a puzzle.

I will use SPeL:

```
<bean id="DsdDetectorLogic" class="my class" init-method="init" lazy-init="true" >
    <property name="threshold" value="#{ properties.threshold }" />
    <property name="lag" value="#{ (1 > new Integer(properties.lag ) or 
                                    new Integer(properties.lag ) > 3) ? 1 : 
                                    properties.lag  }" />
    ...
</bean>
```